# set_message in codeigniter doesn't work

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter-2, codeigniter

i am going to change the validation message for a specific rule called **accept** in codeigniter. it is a checkbox. i tried this code according to **codeigniter's documentation**:

```
function register()
{
    //validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sex', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_sex_label'), 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_fname_label'), 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_lname_label'), 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_email_label'), 'required|valid_email|trim|is_unique[users.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_phone_label'), 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mob', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_mob_label'), 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_address_label'), 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_company_label'), 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('agentcode', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_agentcode_label'), 'required|trim|xss_clean', 'callback_ins');
    function callback_ins ($ins)
    {
        if ($ins == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_username_label'), 'required|trim|xss_clean|is_unique[users.username]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_password_label'), 'required|min_length[' . $this->config->item('min_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|max_length[' . $this->config->item('max_password_length', 'ion_auth') . ']|matches[password_confirm]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_confirm', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_password_confirm_label'), 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('accept', 'Accept', 'callback_accept_check');
    function accept_check($str)
{
    if ($str == '') {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('accept_check', 'برای ایجاد یک حساب کاربری، باید قوانین سایت را مطالعه کرده و موافقت خود را با آن اعلام نمایید.');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        $username = strtolower($this->input->post('username'));
        $email    = strtolower($this->input->post('email'));
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $additional_data = array(
            'sex'        => $this->input->post('sex'),
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name'  => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'phone'      => $this->input->post('phone'),
            'mob'        => $this->input->post('mob'),
            'address'    => $this->input->post('address'),
            'company'    => $this->input->post('company'),
            'agentcode'  => $this->input->post('agentcode')
        );
    }
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data))
    {
        //check to see if we are creating the user
        //redirect them back to the admin page
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
        redirect("main/users", 'refresh');
    }
    else
    {
        //display the create user form
        //set the flash data error message if there is one
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->ion_auth->errors() ? $this->ion_auth->errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message')));

        $this->_render_page('registration', $this->data);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work and it shows the default message for required validation! even i cant set the message manually by callback function just for this rule whats the problem?

Comment: what is `accept`? did you load `$this->load->library('form_validation');`?

Comment: @Phil its a **checkbox** field in my view. yes i did! it works everywhere except this one!

Comment: can I see more of the `php` and the `html` I don't have much to go on right here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [CI user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors), you should pass the `rule` as the first parameter to the `set_message()` method, **NOT** the input name:

```php
$this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');
```

In your case, it should be:

```php
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'برای ایجاد یک حساب کاربری، باید قوانین سایت را مطالعه کرده و موافقت خود را با آن اعلام نمایید.');
```

> but just i want to set message for accept field.

Then you need to use a **[callback function](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)** as the validation rule, as follows:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('accept', 'Accept', 'callback_accept_check');
```

Then within the Controller add a method called `accept_check`. For instance:

```php
public function accept_check($str)
{
    if ($str == '') {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('accept_check', 'برای ایجاد یک حساب کاربری، باید قوانین سایت را مطالعه کرده و موافقت خود را با آن اعلام نمایید.');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: but just i want to set message for accept field. this code will be change all the required validation's messages

Comment: @Hashem Qolami i tried this solution too, but it doesn't work: `$this->form_validation->set_rules('accept', 'قوانین', 'callback_accept_check');
  function callback_accept_check ($str)
  {
   if(!isset($str) OR empty($str))
   {
    $this->form_validation->set_message('accept_check', 'برای ایجاد یک حساب کاربری، باید قوانین سایت را مطالعه کرده و موافقت خود را با آن اعلام نمایید.');
    return false;
   }
  }`

Comment: Could yo expand on `it doesn't work`? Did you follow the sample prepared in the User guide? Any error you've got?

Comment: Could you update the question by adding the current code you've tried so far? I mean the relevant code from the Controller.

Comment: :( the problem is other parts of the form works correctly and any error doesn't occur.

Comment: @mojtaba Have you declared the `accept_check()` function inside the `register()` method?! The `accept_check()` MUST be a method of your Controller class. For instance, take a look at [`username_check()` method in the CI user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks).

Comment: @HashemQolami Thanks but i did this for `callback_ins` too and it works! why?

Comment: @mojtaba Not sure about that at the moment, It needs to get hands (again) dirty with the core files.